# Calculation confusing of conjugate in CT fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, continuous-signals, conjugate

when calculate conjugate of $$X(f)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t)e^{-j2\pi ft}dt ,\tag{1}$$ I can get $$X^*(f)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t)^*e^{j2\pi ft}dt ,\tag{2}$$ so $$F[x^*(t)]=X^*(-f).\tag{3}$$ But if I calculate from the other way, $$x(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X(f)e^{j2\pi ft}df,\tag{4}$$ so the conjugate is $$x^*(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X^*(f)e^{-j2\pi ft}df=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} -X^*(-f)e^{j2\pi ft}df,\tag{5}$$ so $$F[x^*(t)]=-X^*(-f), \tag{6}$$
why I get the different result of (3) and (6) ?

Comment: Are you missing a change in the sign of your limits in (5) when you did f -> -f?  That would fix the minus sign (6)

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome oh... I see, shame on my calculation, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@GrapefruitIsAwsome's comment is spot on. You made a mistake with the variable substitution (sign change of the limits). The correct steps are

$$\begin{align}x^*(t)&=\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}X(f)e^{j2\pi ft}df\right]^*\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}X^*(f)e^{-j2\pi ft}df\\&=\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}X^*(-f)e^{j2\pi ft}(-df)\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}X^*(-f)e^{j2\pi ft}df\\&=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left\{X^*(-f)\right\}\end{align}$$

Comment: Ah yes I see now! Nice answer

Comment: yeah, a very clear answer, thanks so much!